# PolymerJS retrieving multiple inputs from the user

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am a front end noob and so far I have come to a point where I can POST to a RoR backend. I'm stuck right now as I want a simple method for the user to input multiple instructor_ids in the same form

```
i.e. "instructor_ids" : [1,2,3] in the json
```

I know this is not the right method but this is what I've done:

```
<paper-input label="Instructor IDs" id="course-instructor-id-list" value="{{item.instructor_ids}}" floatingLabel></paper-input>
```

How can I make the user input multiple values for the same element? Can someone please guide me? I did Google but I just seem to read a lot but nothing relevant.

Because of this inability to send over an array of ids the backend is unable to process the JSON giving me a 422.

Comment: Maybe you can try turning the input value into an array first before sending it. You can use [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split it by comma or space.

Comment: Cool, let me try this out!